# Why is there no IAM role specific to calling a GCP function?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

If I look at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles#standard-roles I see:

- roles/cloudfunctions.admin
- roles/cloudfunctions.developer
- roles/cloudfunctions.viewer
- roles/cloudfunctions.invoker

The latter contains only one permission, `cloudfunctions.functions.invoke`

We are using Google Cloud Workflows to call our cloud function and its currently failing with error:

```
"error": {
 "code": 403,
 "message": "Permission 'cloudfunctions.functions.call' denied on resource 'projects/redacted/locations/europe-west2/functions/funcname' (or resource may not exist).",
 "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
 }
```

I surprised me that given there is a roles/cloudfunctions.invoker role that is no roles/cloudfunctions.caller that includes `cloudfunctions.functions.call`. roles/cloudfunctions.developer includes that permission but many other things as well Why is there no such role?

And yes, I know I can create a custom role, would just be nice if I didn't have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extra info

> You cannot increase the CALL quota. Insufficient quota generally occurs if you mistakenly use this API to invoke your functions in production. Please keep in mind that this API is meant for testing via Cloud Console or ' gcloud functions call CLI, and it cannot handle heavy traffic.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/quotas#rate_limits

Answer (score 2):

As I understand the [Cloud Functions IAM Permissions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/permissions):

`cloudfunctions.functions.call` => `Call the callFunction API.`
`cloudfunctions.functions.invoke` => `Invoke an HTTP function via its public URL.`

You mentioned that "We are using Google Cloud Workflows to **call** our cloud function"... Not sure, but probably you are about this method - [projects.locations.functions.call](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/call). It is stated on that page: "To be used for testing purposes as very limited traffic is allowed."

I don't know all details of your context and requirements, but can you **invoke** the cloud function using its URL?

Comment: Thx for the answer, it does look like invoking is what we should be doing. Interestingly we’re using a different google API (I.e. in Workflows) that wraps calls to projects.locations.functions.call

Comment: Actually, to be fair, Workflows’ own documentation does invoke the function rather than call it https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/cloudfunctions/Overview

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/cloudfunctions/Overview#module_googleapiscloudfunctionsv1projectslocationsfunctions - "call" - "Synchronously invokes a deployed Cloud Function. To be used for testing purposes as very limited traffic is allowed." I am not sure, that looking into the yaml example there - I can find where the function is called (or invoked).

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/cloudfunctions/v1/projects.locations.functions/call#subworkflow_snippet => "call: googleapis.cloudfunctions.v1.projects.locations.functions.call
"